# Getting the Progress Bar to Update when running under a Click command

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is the current tree of my code:

```
Click_test/
├── cli.py
├── cool_stuff
│   ├── commands.py
│   ├── __init__.py
|
├── __init__.py
```

CLI File looks like this:

```
import click
import cool_stuff.commands as cool_stuff

@click.group()
@click.argument("secret", case_sensitive=False)
@click.pass_context
def cli(ctx, secret):
    ctx.obj['secret'] = secret

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli.add_command(cool_stuff.do_something)
    cli(obj={})
```

Commands.py file looks like this:

```
import click
from tqdm import tqdm

@click.command("do_something")
@click.pass_context
def do_something(ctx):
    click.echo(f'Doing some cool stuff...')
    for number in tqdm(range(100), description="Do some cool things"):
        print(f"Secret is {ctx.obj['secret']} {number}")
```

What you will observe here is I'm doing something with the click library. I have a group because I can break out the commands into folders for the sake of scale. Then I add all the desired commands in the main cli py file when done.

Here's the challenge: For some reason, when I take a look at the progress bar, I only see it get to 1, then to 100.

What I noticed is between the first and last iteration, I don't see anything. Even if I want it to print output, it will only show all output at the first iteration, then every output on the last iteration.

Basically, the progress bar isn't working.

Now, if I add a progress bar to the main cli function, it has no problems. It appears my issue only happens when it is used in the child functions.

Has anyone identified this issue previously, and if so, what did you do to resolve it?

PS I also tried the click.progressbar and that does the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

This is solved. It appears that the iterations in which tqdm refreshes in a click subcommand is slower, but still happens at a recurring pace.